# Can an array of a union type be cast to a pointer of the active type?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, unions

Given an array of some `union` type, if the following conditions are met:

- the active member of each `union` in the array is the same,
- `sizeof` each member within the `union` is the same, and
- `alignof` each member within the `union` is the same
- (possibly) the union satisfies the requirements for `StandardLayoutType`

then are the following actions safe:

1. casting this array to a pointer of the active type (for the intent of addressing it as an array of the active type)
2. addressing anything other than the first element of the above array?
3. assuming 1 & 2 are possible; does this hold for non standard-layout-types?

For example, consider the following code-segment:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
union storage_type
{
    T value0;
    U value1;
};

static_assert( sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), "" );
static_assert( alignof(int) == alignof(float), "" );

storage_type<int,float> storage[] = { {1}, {2}, {3} };

// the active type of all storage_type is 'int', so cast to int*
// to be treated as an array of ints

auto* array = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&storage[0]);

assert( array[0] == 1 );
assert( array[1] == 2 );
assert( array[2] == 3 );
```

I'm interested in what the C++ Standard has to explicitly say about such a case. I know that `StandardLayoutType`s are safe to cast to the first member of the structure or active element of the union, so I suspect that my first cast is safe; but I'm unsure if this would hold true for an array, and treating it like an array of the active type.

I tried doing some searching, both on SO and in the C++ standard (N4660 C++17 draft) -- but I didn't have any luck

**Note**: This question is not about whether this will work *in practice* due to compilers having C compatibility; this is strictly a question on whether this invokes UB in C++, and whether it violates strict-aliasing rules.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this can fail. As per standard:

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its data members.

So, in theory, sizeof(my_union) and sizeof(largest_member) might differ.

If you static_assert() that it's the same, then:

```
int* array = &storage[0].value0;
```

... does it and you're UB-free due to how array indexing works.

Comment: Good catch for 12.3\1 quote on the size of the `union`. Though I'm not convinced on the bit about it _not_ being UB. Actually, because of this quote I'm more convinced that it's at best _implementation-defined_ behavior, since whether or not addressing would work would be determined by compiler and platform. Only the first cast to a pointer (1. from my question) would be valid and legal.